# Transforming all variables to log

Tags: logging, stata, ln

I am using Stata, and I would like to generate a log variable based on my current available variables. However, I have too many variables and using `generate` command will take too much time. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?
Say, I am using:

```
gen log_gdp = log(gdp)
```

then I have to do this to every variable.

Is there a way to instead do, for every variable,

```
   gen log_varname = log(varname)
```

Comment: @TheIceBear gave a good answer. Please accept it, or otherwise explain what is unclear or not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ds` in combination with a loop. See `help ds` for options on how to exclude or include different variables. I included `has(type numeric)` to exclude all string variables as you cannot take the log of a string.

See this example using the built-in data set `auto`.

```
sysuse auto

ds, has(type numeric) 
local variables `r(varlist)'

foreach var of local variables {
    gen log_`var' = log(`var') 
}
```

Comment: The OP is well advised to filter out variables with any zeros or negative values. Several ways to do that: one is to transform conditionally on the results of `count if \`var' <= 0` being zero.